# How to log systemd output to container logs

Tags: docker, systemd, containers, journald, podman

I run a rootless container system container with podman, i.e. systemd is running inside the container as entrypoint.

I cannot figure out, though, how I can get the logs of the container, i.e. output of systemd itself and the journal to land into the container logs of podman (what `podman logs <containername>` gives you).

As I understand, podman connects the stdout/stderr of the entrypoint to the container logs fd. But systemd doesn't use that, but instead writes to `/dev/console`.

Thus if I run the container with `-t` I see the systemd output on the terminal (as the vt is mapped into the container as `/dev/console`). But neither with `-t` or without I get anything into the container log. It seems the entrypoint stdout isn't even available anymore in the container at all, because systemd redirects it's own stdin/stdout/stderr to `/dev/null` during startup.

I didn't find any options to make systemd write to stdout or make podman mount its logs fd into the container e.g. as `dev/console`.

I can't believe that problem hasn't been solved. Anyone know a way to do what I intend?

Comment: Have you tried the [documented setting](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) `StandardOutput=fd:stdout` for your service?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the setting completely. According to the documentation `StandardOutput=fd:...` connects the output to a socket unit (which needs to exist).

In any case, I get this, when I try:

`Jan 31 12:56:12 afe26be2ba8e systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to load a named file descriptor: No such file or directory`